# Deployment with ECS and a slow starting task, ignoring ALB health checks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS EC2 Service connected to an ALB, with 3 Tasks running.

The Health Check Grace Period is set to 7200 seconds, it can take over an hour to spin up.

Deployments are done via Cloud Formation that updates the Task Definition with a new ECR Image.

This triggers a deployment on ECS and it successfully stops one old task and starts a new Task. However, after 5 minutes, even though the ALB is still reporting the instance as Unhealthy, ECS continues the deployment, stopping all the old Tasks and spinning up new ones before the first new Task is healthy.

This results the ALB having no available instances and experiencing an outage.

I suspect this is because ECS doesn't really talk to the ALB, just that the ALB will terminate the Task.

I have looked at using Task Definition Health Check but it only has a startPeriod, or grace period, of 300 seconds.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: Please check your task logs. Sometimes if there are any error in startup of  instance then  also it stop tasks arbitrarily or just after startup and try to start new one.

Comment: The tasks start just fine, they are just considered ready by ECS before they are actually ready.

Comment: @dohmoose if you solved the issue, can you post it as answer, please.

Comment: @dohmoose sorry to comment on an old question! But would also be interested in a solution if you ever found one